# Error while creating trigger (SQL developer 3.2)

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I cant seem to find the reason for this error, most examples iv check use this method but my SQL complier seem to have a problem with the / the END statement.

My Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER STUDENTS_ID_TRIG 
BEFORE INSERT ON STUDENTS
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if(:new.STUDENT_ID = null) then
  SELECT STUDENTS_ID_SEQ.nextval
  INTO :new.STUDENT_ID
  FROM dual;
  end if;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "STUDENT_ID_TRIG" ENABLE
```

My Sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "APEX90"."STUDENT_ID_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH                     11 CACHE 10 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
```

The Error

```
Trigger APEX90.STUDENTS_ID_TRIG@APEX90
Error(13,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"
```

Comment: You have "/" after END, just remove that

Comment: The slash is needed when compiling code. The code compiles for me. The only problem I see is using the "=" when checking if a field is NULL. Use "is" instead. But that won't affect the compiling, just the execution.